# change customer community logout URL

Tags: customer-community

I'm leveraging communities but using my own UI with VF pages. For customer portals you were able to set the logout URL, I don't see this option in communities. Does such a thing exist?

**UPDATE**
To clarify I have a custom login page, I'd like it to redirect back to that login page instead of the standard community login page after logout. In the customer portal settings you're able to specify the URL for the logout page to redirect to. I want to know if this is an option with the community.

Comment: can you explain in bit more detail?

Comment: I added more detail

Comment: If I am understanding correct you want your own vf login page and when user logout, it would redirect to your own custom visualforce page instead of default community landing page? @PhilB

Comment: Yes. back to my own vf login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, you can't currently change the logout URL of a community: /secur/logout.jsp

However, if you're rolling your own UI (even in the standard communities UI, you have control over the footer), then you can create your own logout link and page, and manually call /secur/logout.jsp in your page.

Comment: Yeah I saw an example where someone used a javascript timeout redirect and called /secure/logout.jsp inside an invisible iframe. Is that pretty much what you're describing?

Comment: That's exactly what I am describing. Given that logout is not a configurable page at this time, that is your only option.

Comment: Yeah it feels kinda hacky but unfortunately I think this is the best option. I used something similiar to this: http://cloudjedi.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/hiding-the-salesforce-logout-branding-in-force-com-sites/

Answer (score 2):

As of the Winter '15 release, you can set a custom logout page URL under
Administration Settings > Login & Registration.

Check out the documentation here:
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_networks_custom_pages.htm